# How to create a slash in table cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, line, cell

I'm creating a table and want to design the table as below. 
Can anyone tell me how to do like that? or any key word can search online?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to create an image for the diagonal line and then set it as the cell's background.  You'll have to play around with it to get it looking right, but that should work for you.

There is no built-in HTML or CSS property to set this.

Comment: thanks Shark. but this is not a good idea since i will dynamically create the table. image only can be static use. but still, thanks for replay.

Comment: Hey guys,

I just find out another similar post in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127035/how-to-create-a-diagonal-line-within-a-table-cell
this is what i want for.

Maybe you all can go the side and check it out. It is relate to Javascript and Css. 
Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a background image? A cell contains 2 absolutely positioned elements - title/subtitle.

Comment: thanks Bridis. a static image will not fulfill in this dynamic table. but thanks for replay.

Comment: Hey guys,

I just find out another similar post in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127035/how-to-create-a-diagonal-line-within-a-table-cell
this is what i want for.

Maybe you all can go the side and check it out. It is relate to Javascript and Css. 
Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 1):

a reasonably simple way would be to create and image and place it in
your table cell.

Comment: Hey guys,

I just find out another similar post in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127035/how-to-create-a-diagonal-line-within-a-table-cell
this is what i want for.

Maybe you all can go the side and check it out. It is relate to Javascript and Css. 
Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to add a line, you can use only css and html to achieve it.

**Example below:**

```css
.slope{
    position: relative;
    width: 1em;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><div class="slope"></div></th>
            <th scope="col">First</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Handle</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```