# Jquery Coordinate of the diagonal line in table cell

Tags: jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, datatable, cell

Currently i's look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127035/how-to-create-a-diagonal-line-within-a-table-cell/8179892#8179892) ([How to create a diagonal line within a table cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127035/how-to-create-a-diagonal-line-within-a-table-cell/8179892#8179892)) and get a very good [answer](http://jsfiddle.net/zw3Ve/23/) (http://jsfiddle.net/zw3Ve/23/) from [Galled](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529689/galled)(https://stackoverflow.com/users/529689/galled).

But i got a problem is about:

how to modify the coordinate of the line. because the line i want display is from top-right to bottom-left. Hope someone can teach me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last jsfiddle given in the other answer uses css transform to rotate the lines. You specify the **angle** you'd like to rotate to.
In the example, the angle value is negative:

```
sDomTemp += '-webkit-transform: rotate(-'+nAnglSex+'deg);';
sDomTemp += '-moz-transform: rotate(-'+nAnglSex+'deg);';
sDomTemp += '-ms-transform: rotate(-'+nAnglSex+'deg);';
sDomTemp += '-o-transform: rotate(-'+nAnglSex+'deg);';
sDomTemp += 'transform: rotate(-'+nAnglSex+'deg);';
```

Make the angle positive and it will rotate the other way (chnage `rotate(-'+` by `rotate('+`):

```
sDomTemp += 'transform: rotate('+nAnglSex+'deg);';
// repeat for the other browser-specific properties
```

For the IE-specific css property `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix()` it uses trigonometry and i don't have IE to test so it's out of my scope, sorry. Anyway, here the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: You are awesome, Didier G! It works. But the line is go out of the cell. Do you have any idea? I use Gridview C#.net. Thanks

Comment: It is work fine now. I just clear the css for this cell. really thanks a lot for you Didier G.